# How to debug single file with Rails environment loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been learning Ruby and now Rails.

I know in VS Code you configure the debugger with the following config

```
            {
                "name": "Debug Ruby",
                "type": "Ruby",
                "request": "launch",
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "program": "${file}",
            },
```

It works just like `ruby xxx.rb` and pauses at breakpoints.

But I want to be able to do the same for any file in my rails project. For example, I just wrote a model `user.rb` for my project and i want to test and debug some functions.I tried the following:

```
            {
                "name": "Rails run",
                "type": "Ruby",
                "request": "launch",
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
                "args": [
                    "runner",
                    "${file}"
                ]
            },
```

but this wont stop at the breakpoints. there's also `rails server` option but that's for running the whole app but i just want to test&debug one single piece of code.

Comment: how about you just run the single file? and treat it like PORO, if you use vscode `code runner` extensions could help you with that

Comment: @buncis but does it work with vs code debugger?( breakpoints)

Comment: it should be go give it a try @James Yu

Comment: @buncis unfortunately it doesnt work as this only run the code but still need debugger to properly attach to it. it's a very useful tool though!

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesnt work because rdebug doesnt attach to any subprocesses that the runner spins up to run the script. You could try launching the debugger directly from the ruby file you want the runner to use. You'd need to add an attach use-case in the debugger options:

For example:
`.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
    "name" : "Attach to rdebug-ide",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "attach",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "remoteHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "remotePort": "1234",
    "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
},
```

Than in `xxx.rb` add the following to the top of the file:

```rb
require 'ruby-debug-ide'
require 'resource-struct'
options = ResourceStruct::FlexStruct.new({ 
    host: '127.0.0.1', 
    port: '1234' 
})

### Anything above this line will get run twice
Debugger.debug_program(options) unless Debugger.started?
### Rest of code you want to debug
```

Next run `rails r xxx.rb` it displays something like:

```sh
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.3, debase 0.2.4.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:1234
```

Lastly attached your debugger.